# Prove $\sum_1^n 1/i^2 \le 2 - 1/n$ for all natural $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to do this by induction.  It works for $n=1$ because we get $1 \le 2 - 1 = 1$.  Now suppose for some natural $k \ge 1$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^k  \le 2 - 1/k$.  I must show $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \le 2 - 1/(k+1)$.  I started out from the hypothesis and added $1/(k+1)^2$ to both sides of the inequality.  I get

\begin{align*}
  1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \le 2 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
\end{align*}

and it's not obvious what to do from there.  Any hints?

Comment: Can you show that the RHS is $ \leq 2 - 1/(k+1)$? If yes, then you are done.

Comment: I did think of that, but it's not obvious to me how to do it.  Any hints on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
{1\over(k+1)^2}<{1\over k(k+1)}={k+1-k\over k(k+1)}=\frac1k-{1\over k+1}
$$

As a result, we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{1\over i^2}\le2-\frac1k+\frac1k-{1\over k+1}=2-{1\over k+1}
$$

Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, we conclude that the proposition holds for all positive integer $n$.

Comment: That's pretty nice.  This reasoning seems natural to me too, so I'm selecting this approach as the answer here.  Thanks for clearly showing the strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that LHS "grows" slower than RHS

> Prove that $$\frac{1}{n^2} < (2-\frac 1n) - (2-\frac{1}{n-1}), n>1$$

Comment: I don't see the connection between this inequality and the original problem.  I see that $1/n^2$ is the last term of the LHS.  I see that $2 - 1/n$ is the RHS.  But you're subtracting $2 - 1/(n - 1)$,  Why $1/(n - 1)$?  Anyhow, I don't see how this inequality would imply the original one.

Comment: Thanks @Brian M. Scott for correcting my typo.

Comment: @NeatMath: You’re welcome.

Comment: Oh, I see!  That works too!  Thanks!